# Pass a value to a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class defined like this in my python code:

```
class testclass():

    def test(self):
        baseUrl = "url" # I need to get the value of URL here


#Main
url = "fqdn.illumina.com"
```

Now how do I pass the value of the url fqdn.domain.com into the function test? Could someone provide me a hint? I will build my code on top of this.

Thank you

Comment: Like you would do for any function? [ask] and [mre]

Comment: its a global ... you can just remove the quotes ... but thats not exactly "passing it in"

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic question and you need to refer to references to learn. Here is a starting point:

```
class testclass():
    def __init__(self, url=None):
        self.baseUrl = url

    def test(self, url):
        self.baseUrl = url # I need to get the value of URL here


#Main
url = "fqdn.illumina.com"
object_ = testclass()
object_.test(url)
print(object_.baseUrl)
```

Comment: based on the class and def names im guessing he is running this with pytest or something ... so this method likely wouldnt work... but it does answer the question the OP actually asked so +1 ...  maybe im wrong and the OP will be directly invoking this

Answer (score 0):

## if baseUrl is function argument

```
class testclass():

    def test(self, url):
        baseUrl =url
        print(baseUrl)

url = "fqdn.illumina.com"
class_obj = testclass()
class_obj.test(url)
```

## if baseUrl is object's properties

```
class testclass():
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.baseUrl = url

    def test(self):
        baseUrl = self.baseUrl
        print(baseUrl)


url = "fqdn.illumina.com"
class_obj = testclass(url)
class_obj.test()
```